# Does Python support something like literal objects?

Tags: python, oop, scala, singleton, object-literal

In Scala I could define an abstract class and implement it with an object:

```
abstrac class Base {
    def doSomething(x: Int): Int
}

object MySingletonAndLiteralObject extends Base {
    override def doSomething(x: Int) = x*x
}
```

My concrete example in Python:

```
class Book(Resource):

    path = "/book/{id}"

    def get(request):
        return aBook
```

Inheritance wouldn't make sense here, since no two classes could have the same `path`. And only one instance is needed, so that the class doesn't act as a blueprint for objects. With other words: no class is needed here for a `Resource` (`Book` in my example), but a base class is needed to provide common functionality.

I'd like to have:

```
object Book(Resource):

    path = "/book/{id}"

    def get(request):
        return aBook
```

What would be the Python 3 way to do it?

Comment: Why is path a class variable and not an instance variable?

Comment: `path` is a class variable, because the path is valid for the whole class and not limited to a specific instance. But since there is only one instance it doesn't matter anyway.

Comment: @deamon: actually, I think @S.Lott has a point. Why can't you make a generic `Book` class, instantiate it once, and use that instance as your book?

Comment: @katrielalex: I could do so, but I'd like to rule out the possibility that derived classes had the same `path`. For this purpose it doesn't matter whether it is a class or an instance variable.

Comment: @deamon: Yes, it does! If you instantiate a `Book( <path-to-book> )` then you get a `Book` with that path. If you make a `PaperbackBook( Book )`, it wouldn't automatically get the *instance variable* of your other `Book`.

Comment: @katrielalex ... but in my concrete scenario the initialisation would be performed in the `__init__` method, so that subclasses would inherit the instance variable when they call `super()`. But when I change my application design a bit, I could go with instance variables.

Answer (score 7):

#### Use a decorator to convert the inherited class to an object at creation time

I believe that the concept of such an object is not a typical way of coding in Python, but if you must then the decorator `class_to_object` below for immediate initialisation will do the trick. Note that any parameters for object initialisation must be passed through the decorator:

```
def class_to_object(*args):
    def c2obj(cls):
        return cls(*args)
    return c2obj
```

using this decorator we get

```
>>> @class_to_object(42)
... class K(object):
...     def __init__(self, value):
...         self.value = value
... 
>>> K
<__main__.K object at 0x38f510>
>>> K.value
42
```

The end result is that you have an object `K` similar to your scala object, and there is no class in the namespace to initialise other objects from.

Note: To be pedantic, the class of the object K can be retrieved as `K.__class__` and hence other objects may be initialised if somebody really want to. In Python there is almost always a way around things if you really want.

Answer (score 2):

Use an [`abc`](http://docs.python.org/library/abc.html) (Abstract Base Class):

```
import abc
class Resource( metaclass=abc.ABCMeta ):
    @abc.abstractproperty
    def path( self ):
        ...
        return p
```

Then anything inheriting from `Resource` is required to implement `path`. Notice that `path` is actually implemented in the ABC; you can access this implementation with `super`.

Comment: But what should I do with an ABC? An ABC would lead to the same class as shown above.

Comment: @deamon: Yes, but it's *abstract*. Subclasses are required to override the abstract properties and methods.

Comment: It would be better than a concrete superclass - I agree so far. But the subclass is still a class from which other classes could inherit (the `path`).

Comment: @deamon: Yes, that is correct. Subclassing `Book` is not an inherently bad idea -- what if you wanted a `PaperbackBook`? There is a very elegant way to do this in Python, which is the Borg pattern: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/66531-singleton-we-dont-need-no-stinkin-singleton-the-bo/.

Comment: Interesting [discussion of the borg pattern](http://tarekziade.wordpress.com/2009/01/22/singletons-and-borg-are-unpythonic-well-imvho/).

Comment: @deamon: yes, although it is also supported by the great Alex Martelli so it must be getting something right! See @aaronasterling's answer for a way to prevent inheritance, if you are *sure* that you want to do that.

Answer (score 1):

If you can instantiate `Resource` directly you just do that and stick the path and `get` method on directly.

```
from types import MethodType

book = Resource()
def get(self):
    return aBook
book.get = MethodType(get, book)
book.path = path
```

This assumes though that `path` and `get` are not used in the `__init__` method of `Resource` and that path is not used by any class methods which it shouldn't be given your concerns.

If your primary concern is making sure that nothing inherits from the `Book` non-class, then you could just use this metaclass

```
class Terminal(type):
    classes = []
    def __new__(meta, classname, bases, classdict):
        if [cls for cls in meta.classes if cls in bases]:
            raise TypeError("Can't Touch This")
        cls = super(Terminal, meta).__new__(meta, classname, bases, classdict)
        meta.classes.append(cls)
        return cls

class Book(object):
    __metaclass__ = Terminal

class PaperBackBook(Book):
    pass
```

You might want to replace the exception thrown with something more appropriate. This would really only make sense if you find yourself instantiating a lot of one offs.

And if that's not good enough for you and you're using CPython, you could always try some of this hackery:

```
class Resource(object):
    def __init__(self, value, location=1):
        self.value = value
        self.location = location

with Object('book', Resource, 1, location=2):
    path = '/books/{id}'
    def get(self):
        aBook = 'abook' 
        return aBook

print book.path
print book.get()
```

made possible by my very first context manager.

```
class Object(object):
    def __init__(self, name, cls, *args, **kwargs):
        self.cls = cls
        self.name = name
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def __enter__(self):
        self.f_locals = copy.copy(sys._getframe(1).f_locals)

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        class cls(self.cls):
            pass
        f_locals = sys._getframe(1).f_locals
        new_items = [item for item in f_locals if item not in self.f_locals]
        for item in new_items:
            setattr(cls, item, f_locals[item])
            del f_locals[item] # Keyser Soze the new names from the enclosing namespace
        obj = cls(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
        f_locals[self.name] = obj # and insert the new object
```

Of course I encourage you to use one of my above two solutions or Katrielalex's suggestion of ABC's.

Comment: -1 That won't work, because `get` here is a function instead of a bound method (are they called that in Py3k? something like that...). If you really want to do this sort of thing, you need to instantiate one of the types in `types`. But that doesn't solve the problem anyway, because what is `Resource().path` meant to be?

Comment: @katrielalex  Right. my original idea works with classes. My edits fix it though. `book.path` will be available as `self.path` for all instance methods.

Comment: @aaron: now it works, but it's not 'right' -- monkeypatching classes to add crucial state is not exactly good design. Prepare to be assimilated.

Comment: also, i'm not sure that it's bad design to monkypatch a `book` psuedo-class if it's _part of the design_ that there is only ever one. It's actually considered to be fairly pythonic.

Comment: @aaron: heh, cute! It does solve the OP's problem now. I'm not sure I like the idea of preventing somebody subclassing `Book` -- what if you want `PaperbackBook`s? -- but that's more a matter of taste than correctness I think.

Comment: @Katrielalex  I personally agree. It's not my job to control what people do with my classes, It's my job to not get in their way. It's what the OP wants though.

Comment: @aaron: true that =). Oh, I think it should be a TypeError, at least based on how `abc` does it.